# For each "group": sum the respective volume and colli count

Tags: vba

I have a lot of data at hand concerning what we call `ExWorks`. This is the term for orders that consist of a mix of products from different brands. And the way our system handles this at the moment is that it splits this order up into multiple, which makes it hard to see which orders are actually the same.

My task is to find out how many of these sorts of orders we get, what the total volume is and what the total `colli` count is.

Image of a cutout of some of the data:

[image: image taken from https://imgur.com/a/Qczh1FU]

The way it works is that for every "TRUE", that row, and the one above (up to and including the first blank) is actually the same order. So like in the picture, row 2 and 3 are, in reality, the same order, row 37, 38 and 39 is the same order and so on.

(I really hope this makes sense)

So far I've managed to write a primitive VBA code that counts the amount of `ExWork` orders, but I don't know how to get it to sum the volume and colli count for each of these `ExW` orders.

```
 Sub FindAntalExW_VolColli()

    ' Variable
    Dim douAntal As Double

    ' Starting cell
    Range("A2").Select

    ' Hastighed - Til
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ' Run through data
    Do Until ActiveCell.Text = ""

        ' Find "first" TRUE
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Text = "TRUE" Then
            ' Opdate number
            douAntal = douAntal + 1

            ' Find number after eachother
            If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Text = "TRUE" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                Do Until ActiveCell.Text = ""
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Loop
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
            End If

        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop


    ' Write number of ExW orders
    Range("I2").Value = douAntal

    ' Hastighed - Fra
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
 End Sub
```

What I ultimately want, is some code that, like the one above, counts the number of `ExWork` orders, but for each `ExW` order, it sums the respective volume and `colli` count in the `Kombi Vol` and `Kombi Colli Count` columns as seen in the imgur link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a program that should do what you're looking for. You'll need to update the sheetName variable in the main function, but other then that, it you shouldn't have to make any changes

```
Sub main()
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim lastRow, searchStartRow, orderEndRow As Long

    'set the sheet name we're working in
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    With Sheets(sheetName)
        'find the last row containing an order
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'start search on row 2, just below the headers
        searchStartRow = 2

        For ctr = searchStartRow To lastRow
            If (.Cells(ctr, 2).Value = True) Then 'we've found a kombi order
                orderEndRow = findOrderEnd(sheetName, ctr, (lastRow))
                Call sumOrder(sheetName, ctr - 1, orderEndRow)
                ctr = orderEndRow 'start looking for the next order after the end row of the previous one.
            End If
        Next ctr
    End With
End Sub

Function findOrderEnd(ByVal sheetName As String, startRow, endRow As Long)
    If (startRow = endRow) Then 'we don't need to check where the end is because we've already reached the last row
        findOrderEnd = endRow
    Else
        With Sheets(sheetName)
            For ctr = startRow To endRow
                If (Trim(.Cells(ctr, 2).Value) = "") Then 'the previous cell was the end
                    findOrderEnd = ctr - 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ctr
        End With
    End If
End Function

Sub sumOrder(ByVal sheetName As String, startRow, endRow As Long)
    With Sheets(sheetName)
        .Cells(endRow, 5).Formula = "=SUM(C" & startRow & ":C" & endRow & ")"
        .Cells(endRow, 6).Formula = "=SUM(D" & startRow & ":D" & endRow & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!.. tho its not quiet what Im looking for. I probably did a bad job trying to explain it, but the way the data is Sorted at the moment, for every TRUE (like in the imgur link) that cell and the ONE (blank) cell above that is actually the same order. BUT, should there be multiple TRUE'es in the cells, then those TRUES'es up until and INCLUDING the ONE blank cell above them, is actually the same order, just like in the imgur, where row 37,38 and 39 is the same order. What I then want, is for their respective volume and colli count to be summed in the far right colums

Comment: In other words, there is always ONE blank cell along with the TRUE (the one blank above it): 1x TRUE with blank = 1 order, 2x TRUE with blank = 1 order. I really don't know how else to put it

Comment: @AndreasRasmussen I have updated my solution. It should be properly grouping the orders now.

Comment: Cant test the code as of now. Im getting a run-error "1004"... It marks the sumOrder sub in which the sum formula is used, but I cant seem to figure it out. It feels like that run-error is just some "catch all" error message, and that the sumOrder sub might not be the real problem..

Comment: I suspect theres a problem with the searchStartRow. It only sum the very first group and then gives the error. I think by not setting searchstartRow equal to where the first group ends, it goes back to search at row 2 in an endless loop.. That said, I still cant fix it.

Comment: The program works perfectly for me when I run it on test data that is similar to the spreadsheet you upload a picture of. Is it breaking on the very first group? Are any formulas added before the runtime error?

Comment: searchStartRow cannot be the problem because it is not used inside the for loop. It is only used to set ctr initial value. Look up how to debug a vba project and step through the code. You can move your mouse over variables to see there values while stepping through it and you can see exactly where it goes wrong that way instead of making guesses.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, Ive been away. Yes, it breaks on the very first group. When debugging, I cant step through the code. It insists that the sum functions are the problem.

Comment: I can only help you so much. I can't tell you what is wrong with the information you've provided me. What is the error message that you are receiving? Did you make sure to rename the "sheetName" variable to the sheet that you're working in?

Comment: The error is: "Run time error 1004; Application-defined or object-defined error", and then proceeds to highlight the sum functions. And yes Ive renamed accordingly.

Comment: That probably means that the sum function is trying to use a range that doesn't exist. This could be because you didn't properly rename the worksheet variable or the layout of your sheet is different from the test one that i wrote the function in. Double check the values that the ranges that are being used in the functions and make sure they're referring to where they're supposed to on your worksheet.

Comment: That's not the case, im fairly sure. Ive renamed the sheet variable proberly, the layout is the same, just 3,5k rows instead of 100. It sums the first group correctly, but then breaks and gives the error. Tho I can see, that the next startrow is being set to 17, which is correct. So its doing the right thing, but I just don't know what breaks it..

Comment: I can see endrow is set to 0, down in the sumOrder sub, in the formula. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: It's absolutely causing the problem and endRow is being set by the findOrderEnd function. You'll have to step through your code like I said, I'd place the breakpoint right at the start of the function, and see why that is the case. It's happening right after the first order, so it shouldn't take too long to diagnose.

Comment: Maybe ive just starred myself blind at this point, I cant see why it does this, but after it find the first endrow, which is 3 and then sums the cells correctly, it then proceeds to find the next endrow from the previous, and does so correctly, but THEN when it hits the blank under the new endrow (ctr hits a blank) its supposed to know that the previous cell was the end, but it dosnt. It keeps going, indefinatly.

Comment: I've adjusted the IF statement that findOrderEnd() uses to determine where the endRow is. Please give it a go and see if this resolves your issue. Before, the if statement was checking if the cell was empty. However, if the cells had white space then they're not truly empty which would cause the if statement to search all to way to the end looking for one. Now I call the Trim() function inside the if statement which will remove white space before checking if it's empty.

Comment: That did it indeed, now its working flawlessly! Thanks a bunch for all the help Tom, I really do appreciate it!